# Webpack dev server React Content Security Policy error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, content-security-policy

I have my single page app running on webpack-dev-server. I can load and reload my entry route over at `localhost:8080` and it works every time. However i can load `localhost:8080/accounts/login` only via a link from within the app i.e whenever i reload `localhost:8080/accounts/login` from the browser refresh button i get

```
Cannot GET /accounts/login/
```

as the server response, and on the console i get

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“default-src http://localhost:8080”). Source:
>   ;(function installGlobalHook(window) { ....

This is my CSP header on the single page app's index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I am also not using any `devtool` on my `webpack.config.json`. What am i missing.

Comment: It appears that document is being served with a Content-Security-Policy header which specifies a stricter policy that has `default-src http://localhost:8080`. If multiple CSP policies are specified, the stricter one always wins. You can override a strict CSP policy specified in one place (e.g., HTTP header) with a more-liberal CSP policy specified somewhere else (e.g., `meta` element)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem that you have. Out of sideshowbarkers comment I still don't really get how to solve the issue. Can you maybe point me in some direction by giving me a useful link or explain your solution a bit more detailed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use Webpack in your project, please add `output.publicPath = '/'` and `devServer.historyApiFallback = true` in your webpack config file.

More info: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

Comment: I think you misquoted the answer from the other question already answered, it's: `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true, contentBase: './' }`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a couple hours to fix this issue. There is a just simple code that you have to add. Just follow the instruction of below. If you face problem to browse from specific url to another url, you will be able to fix that also. If you would like to configure from webpack config file, then write below's code.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

And If you would like to run by cli command, then use the below's code.

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback"
```

It worked for me. I had not to do anything else to fix this issue like meta tag or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails and Webpacker and get this error, note that the initializer `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` has a Content Security Policy for `Rails.env.development`. Changing `:https` to `:http` on that line solved the error for me. (And remember that localhost is not the same as 127.0.0.1 as far as the CSP is concerned.)

Answer (score 0):

adding `output: { ..., publicPath: "/", }` and `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }`   worked

in `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "main.js",
    publicPath: "/", // ++ 
  },
  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    port: "6060",
    static: ["./public"],
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
    historyApiFallback: true, // ++
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      // CSS rules
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue. Had to remove the `contentBase` line from `devServer` configuration in `webpack.config.js`.

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/assets/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 9002
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```