# Content Security Policy error using webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, content-security-policy

I'm using:

```
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/assets/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9002
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

My src/index.js contains

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Curve!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I start webpack-dev-server and go to localhost:9002 I get the following error:

```
Content Security Policy: 
The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src http://localhost:9002”). 
Source: ;(function installGlobalHook(window) {
```

Why is that so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422290/webpack-dev-server-react-content-security-policy-error

Comment: Actually that solution there didn't solve my issue, I saw it before. But it is the same question actually. I posted the solution there.

Comment: I might look deeper into this in a few hours (no promises) but in the meantime I suggest creating the worlds simplest express script and using that as a dev server. Express supports all the same features but you can change your own servers source code to fix stuff like this. A simple Express app only has to be about 10-15 lines long, just borrow some "hello world" project for express and you'll have an equally legit dev server as the webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes. A said above, I posted the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422290/webpack-dev-server-react-content-security-policy-error