# How to configure CSP header for Webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Running webpack-dev-server for my react app is suddenly giving me an error re: default-src being set to 'none' in the CSP (Content Security Policy) header. CSPs are not enabled by Webpack by default per their docs, and there were no changes (to my knowledge) that would have enabled them. This project is using react 16.9.0 and webpack-dev-server 3.8.0

I've tried each suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422290/webpack-dev-server-react-content-security-policy-error), updating the webpack config to change the header to default-src self and using react-helmet to add meta tags. I did not use create-react-app for this project, and most of the other suggestions I've seen are specific to a project created with such with an HTML file entry point.

I need to identify where the CSP header is being enabled and either disable it or change the default-src. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.